# Use of conditions in extracting values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I am currently working on a program for plotting class samples and I dont understand the following lines

```
(x= X[y==cl, 0],
 y=X[y==cl,1])
```

inside the program below:

```
for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
    plot.scatter(x=X[y==cl, 0], 
               y= X[y==cl, 1],
               alpha =0.8, c=colors[idx],
               marker = markers[idx], label=cl, edgecolor='black')
```

Please can anybody offer me a help to deeply understand the lines I mentioned above ? Thank you

Comment: did you check the numpy documentation about indexing?

Comment: Yes I did. But what I didn't catch specifically in the code is the condition "y==cl" inside the assignment process x = X[0] and y= X[1].   Thanks

Comment: `y==cl` returns an array with dimensions of `y`, that is filled with `True` and `False` values. Now `X[y==cl]` produces a `view` of `X` that only contains the values of `X` where `y==cl` is `True`.